# momentjs parse german date string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to parse the String using momentjs:

```
let date = "19. Juli 2016 05:00";
```

The string contains the month of july written in german and it has the "LLL" format according to the momentjs doc.

When I try to parse it with

```
moment(date,'LLL');
```

I get a wrong date.

When I try to parse it with

```
moment(date,'LLL','de');
```

I get the error message:

> TypeError: config._locale is null.

How can I correctly parse this string?

Comment: Have you included the German locale?

Comment: can you further explain that ?

Comment: By that comment I'm guessing the answer is "no." [Read the docs.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use corresponding `moment-locales` dependency to be able to recognize dates in other languages. You can find the [list of locales here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/) and use it from the CDN, or download and bundle it yourself from [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) (get the one that says `moment-with-locales.js`)

And in that case use the following parse method (as you've tried it already):

```
let momentObj = moment(DATE_STRING, FORMAT, LOCALE);
```

## Demo

```js
let momentObj = moment("04. Juli 2016 05:00", 'LLL', 'de');
console.log(momentObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/locale/de.js"></script>
```